# Get distinct days from a collection of dates in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to populate a date range picker display with highlighted cells where data exists in my database. I thus need to reduce my collection to an array of dates where records exist e.g.

```
// collection
[{
  timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-28T20:42:00.000Z"),
  data: 1,
},{
  timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-28T18:42:00.000Z"),
  data: 10,
},{
  timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-28T15:42:00.000Z"),
  data: 100,
},{
  timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-25T15:42:00.000Z"),
  data: 1000,
},{
  timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-17T15:42:00.000Z"),
  data: 10000,
}]
```

reduces to:

```
['2020-01-28', '2020-01-25', '2020-01-17']
```

The nature of the data stored in my database means that if any data exists on a given date, lots of data exists on that date. It is therefore slow to query the entire collection for a given date range and then reduce the result.

Is there a fast(er) way to query a collection to return the distinct set of dates on which data exists?

Comment: Probably best to just track your available dates in a separate collection.

Comment: You're probably right! If a good solution doesn't crop up to this then I'll fall back on that

Comment: Batters did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know you can only get json format result from mongodb query.

I could get the following result, which can be easily converted to the string array in javascript code:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "20200125"
  },
  {
    "_id": "20200117"
  },
  {
    "_id": "20200128"
  }
]
```

I used [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) aggregation operator inside $project stage.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      date: {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%Y%m%d",
          date: "$timestamp"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$date"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5rphRlanniR)

Comment: Awesome thanks, this seems to run fast, just need to port it to mongoose now!

Comment: @Batters you are welcolme, if you have any problem integrating to mongoose, I can help.

Comment: I'll post another question for the mongoose integration if I can't get it working